# SQL select unique values and merge the respective values in other clumns

Tags: sql

I don't know if I made myself clear from the title as I am a complete noob in SQL.
Basically I have a table similar to this:

```
customer number        |       order number
--------------------------------------------
1234                              12
1234                              13
1234                              14
6793                              20
6793                              22
3210                              53

etc.
```

What I would like to achieve is one of the following as I am not sure which is possibe.

1. Select 10 customers and display all their order numbers in one cell, for example:

   ```
   1234               |   12, 13, 14
   6793               |   20,22
   3210               |   53
   ```

or

2. A table similar to the first one but where the total number of unique customers is 10, not 10 rows in the table. Like in the table we have 6 rows but 3 customers. I do not care how many rows, I need all order numbers from 10 customers.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("customer number" int, "order number" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 ("customer number", "order number")
         VALUES (1234, 12)
    INTO Table1 ("customer number", "order number")
         VALUES (1234, 13)
    INTO Table1 ("customer number", "order number")
         VALUES (1234, 14)
    INTO Table1 ("customer number", "order number")
         VALUES (6793, 20)
    INTO Table1 ("customer number", "order number")
         VALUES (6793, 22)
    INTO Table1 ("customer number", "order number")
         VALUES (3210, 53)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

> Query -

```
select "customer number" as customer_number, listagg("order number",',')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "order number") as value
FROM Table1
group by "customer number"
order by "customer number";
```

> Output -

```
CUSTOMER_NUMBER VALUE
1234    12,13,14
3210    53
6793    20,22
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using MS SQL and it doesn't seem to understand listagg.

Comment: do you know the equivalent for MS SQL?